# gunicorn with gevent workers: Using a shared global list

Tags: python, gunicorn, gevent

I am trying to implement Server-Sent Events in my Flask application by following this simple recipe: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/116/

For serving the app, I use gunicorn with gevent workers.

A minimal version of my code looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing

from gevent.queue import Queue
from gunicorn.app.base import BaseApplication
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask('minimal')
# NOTE: This is the global list of subscribers
subscriptions = []


class ServerSentEvent(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.event = None
        self.id = None
        self.desc_map = {
            self.data: "data",
            self.event: "event",
            self.id: "id"
        }

    def encode(self):
        if not self.data:
            return ""
        lines = ["%s: %s" % (v, k)
                 for k, v in self.desc_map.iteritems() if k]
        return "%s\n\n" % "\n".join(lines)


@app.route('/api/events')
def subscribe_events():
    def gen():
        q = Queue()
        print "New subscription!"
        subscriptions.append(q)
        print len(subscriptions)
        print id(subscriptions)
        try:
            while True:
                print "Waiting for data"
                result = q.get()
                print "Got data: " + result
                ev = ServerSentEvent(unicode(result))
                yield ev.encode()
        except GeneratorExit:
            print "Removing subscription"
            subscriptions.remove(q)
    return Response(gen(), mimetype="text/event-stream")


@app.route('/api/test')
def push_event():
    print len(subscriptions)
    print id(subscriptions)
    for sub in subscriptions:
        sub.put("test")
    return "OK"


class GunicornApplication(BaseApplication):
    def __init__(self, wsgi_app, port=5000):
        self.options = {
            'bind': "0.0.0.0:{port}".format(port=port),
            'workers': multiprocessing.cpu_count() + 1,
            'worker_class': 'gevent',
            'preload_app': True,
        }
        self.application = wsgi_app
        super(GunicornApplication, self).__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = dict([(key, value) for key, value in self.options.iteritems()
                       if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None])
        for key, value in config.iteritems():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gapp = GunicornApplication(app)
    gapp.run()
```

The problem is that the subscriber's list seems to be different for every worker. This means that if worker #1 handles the `/api/events` endpoint and adds a new subscriber to the list, the client will only receive events that are added when worker #1 also handles the `/api/test` endpoint.

Curiously enough, the actual list object seems to be the same for each worker, since `id(subscriptions)` returns the same value in every worker.

Is there a way around this? I know that I could just use Redis, but the application is supposed to be as self-contained as possible, so I'm trying to avoid any external services.

**Update:** <strike>The cause of the problem seems to be in my embedding of the `gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication` (which is a [new feature in v0.19](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/custom.html)). When running the application from the command-line with `gunicorn -k gevent minimal:app`, everything works as expected</strike>

**Update 2:** The previous suspicion turned out to be wrong, the only reason it worked was because gunicorn's default number of worker processes is `1`, when adjusting the number to fit the code via the `-w` parameter, it exhibits the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> the actual list object seems to be the same for each worker, since
>   id(subscriptions) returns the same value in every worker.

but I think it's not true, the `subscriptions` on each worker is not the same object. Each worker is a individual process, has its own memory space.

For self-contained system, you could develop a tiny system functioned like simple version of `Redis`. For example, using SQLite or ZeroMQ to communicate between these workers.